# how to split list into multiples of 10

Tags: for

```
 for( MetadataService.Metadata metaDataService : createFieldList)
 {
      system.debug('metaDataService '+metaDataService );
      createFieldArray[i] = metaDataService;
      i++;
      system.debug('i value'+i);
 }
 if(createFieldArray.size() > 0)
 {
       system.debug('fdgfgfgfgfg');
        //this is insert statement. 
       List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results = service.createMetadata(createFieldArray);  
 }
```

in this createFieldList variable iam getting more than 10 records but i want to restrict,to get only 10 at a tym.urgent requirement need your help to fix.thanks in advance.

Comment: where is listcreateFieldList  variable?

Comment: it is createFieldList variaBLE.THE PROBLEM IS,iam getting more than 10 records,since iam getting more than 10,it is throwing error,now,i wanted to insert only 10 at a tym,i even dnt hav an idea how to start

Comment: You need to back up in your design a bit. The part where you gather the createField list, you need to return only 10, indicate if there is more, and make another call for the next 10. The exact how will depend on your code for all of this. If you do it here you will have to populate a list make the call, get the rest, make a call, then handled the aggregate results

Answer (score 0):

this is possible throw break keyword skip the remaining records.

```
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> finalMap= new Map<Integer,List<Integer>>();

    Integer index = 0;
    for(Integer i=0;i<100;i++) {
        List<Integer> temp = new List<Integer>();
        if(temp.size()>10) {
            index ++;
        }       

        if(finalMap.containsKey(index))  {
            temp = finalMap.get(index);
        }


        temp.add(i);
        finalMap.put(index,temp);
    }
    for(Integer i : finalmap.keySet()) {
        system.debug(finalMap.get(i));
    }
```

Comment: no ,should not skip,,remaining elements has to be saved by next call.

Comment: modified answer. pls check

Comment: suppose,for one call i can insert 10 records only,if 16 records are there,i need to perform 2 calls and i have to insert 16 records.